# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer - ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I am developing ios app by using swift. I am using xcode7.0.1. with TableViewController. I want to expand when i click row and collapse when i click it again. I am following the tutorial from [gitHub](https://github.com/rcdilorenzo/Cell-Expander). Now i am facing the error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer` `for the key path "frame" from <X.expandTips 0x145d8d20> because it is not registered as an observer.'`

I hope following line of code will causing the issue.

My UITableViewCell class code:

```
func checkHeight(){
        expandaple_view.hidden = (frame.size.height < expandTips.expandedHeight)
    }
    
    func WatchFrameChanges() {
        addObserver(self , forKeyPath: "frame", options: .New, context: nil )
        checkHeight() 
    }
    
    func ignoreFrameChanges(){
       
        removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")
        
    }
    
    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if keyPath == "frame"{
            checkHeight()
        }
    }
```

And in my TableViewController code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       (cell as! expandTips) . WatchFrameChanges()
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        (cell as! expandTips) . ignoreFrameChanges()
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if (indexPath == selectedIndexPath ){
            return expandTips.expandedHeight
        }else {
            return expandTips.defaultHeight
        }
    }
```

I am new to ios. I hope it must be simple issue. Please someone help me to solve this.

I don't know what are the details needs to post here. Please comment if i want to add more details.

Comment: I'm almost completely sure this code is from my YouTube video so I'll go ahead and link to it here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWgr_wNtGPM). This fix for the KVO de-register was actually already made to the repository (https://github.com/rcdilorenzo/Cell-Expander).

Comment: Yes, exactly I am following this GitHub project. This issue is already registered by @mattiaskronberg. I found the solution from this Pastebin link. http://pastebin.com/VaRmuYfU

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the comment of @Leandros I found the solution. Just tracking the observer using boolean variable.

Use of following code, I found the solution:

```
 var frameAdded = false
 func checkHeight(){

        expanding_view.hidden = (frame.size.height < expandTips.expandedHeight)
    }

    func WatchFrameChanges() {
        if(!frameAdded){
        addObserver(self , forKeyPath: "frame", options: .New, context: nil )
            frameAdded = true
        }
    }

    func ignoreFrameChanges() {
          if(frameAdded){
        removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")
            frameAdded = false
        }
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if keyPath == "frame"{
            checkHeight()
        }
    }
    deinit {
        print("deinit called");
        ignoreFrameChanges()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response on the solution.

Answer (score 7):

Removing the KVO observer is throwing an exception, if there is no observer registered.

Unfortunately, there is no way to check if an observer is registered. A well known workaround is to just catch the exception like this (Objective-C):

```
@try {
    [object removeObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(isFinished))];
} @catch (NSException * __unused exception) {}
```

<strike>To do it in Swift, you have to be using Swift 2.1, since until than it lacked support for `try {} catch {}`. You can see how it works in 2.1 [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html).</strike>

**Correction:** Although Swift 2 introduced its own error handling convention, with `do/try/catch` keywords, these do not mean the same thing as they do in Objective-C, and there is still (as of Swift 2.1 and Xcode 7.1) no way in Swift to handle NSExceptions thrown from the system libraries other than to write Objective-C code to `@catch` them, and then call that code from Swift.

You can read more about KVO in general [here](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/), which also has a section about safe unsubscribing which mentions this unfortunate design.

Comment: I change like this. func ignoreFrameChanges() throws -> Void{
        do{
            try         removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }. Now i'm facing two warning "No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression" and " 'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block".

Comment: And still app closing

Comment: It looks like, Swift still can't catch NSExceptions, like Objective-C can. You now have two ways to fix your problem, one ugly, and one good. The ugly way is to write that portion of code in Objective-C, and call it from Swift, and the good way is, to keep track if you have already removed the observer, and not simply not call it, if it is already removed.

Comment: I have created a NSObject category that provides a method safelyRemoveObserver:forKeyPath: 

https://gist.github.com/samuel-mellert/2bb38ba4887aeecac462ad972e25d26f

You have to call that from Swift in order to catch the NSException that is thrown when the observer is currently not registered.