# heightForRowAtIndexPath is called, but the height doesn't change

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath, heightforrowatindexpath

I have a UITableView called myTableView. What I want the tableView to do is actually quite simple. If the user taps a cell it should expand, in other words an accordion to tableView. This part works fine for me, but I also want the Cell to expand when the user taps a marker on a mapView (I'm using Mapbox). The markers have titles which end with a number, I use this number to determine which cell should expand. Therefore I get the number from the title String and create an NSIndexPath (called localIndexPath) with the number as the row. After that I am selecting the according cell manually with:

```
self.myTableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(localIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
```

and after that I call didSelectRowAtIndexPath by:

```
self.tableView(self.myTableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: localIndexPath)
```

this then calls heightForRowAtIndexPath, which is called successfully both ways, but the actual height only changes when I click the cell, not when i click the marker. My question is why is that and how can I make it work both ways?

Heres the code of all the corresponding methods:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class PullUpView: UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet var tableCell: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var hideButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

var view:UIView!
var selectedRowIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: 99, inSection: 0)
var localIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 99, inSection: 0)
//irrelevant code...

//This is the function I call when I click a marker
func callDidSelectRowAtIndexPathManually(clickedAnnotation: String){
    print("MANUALLY: \(clickedAnnotation)")
    var tourNumber: String = "Default"
    if(clickedAnnotation.characters.count == 18){
        let idx = advance(clickedAnnotation.startIndex, 15)
         tourNumber = String(clickedAnnotation[idx])
      //  print("TOUR NUMMER IST: \(tourNumber)")
     //in case of two digit number
    }else if(clickedAnnotation.characters.count == 19){
        let idx = advance(clickedAnnotation.startIndex, 15)
        let idxTwo = advance(clickedAnnotation.startIndex, 16)
         tourNumber = String(clickedAnnotation[idx]) + String(clickedAnnotation[idxTwo])
       // print("TOUR NUMMER IST: \(tourNumber)")
    }
    let tourNumberAsInt = Int(tourNumber)
    print("TOUR NUMMER IST: \(tourNumberAsInt)")
    if(tourNumberAsInt != nil){
    localIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: tourNumberAsInt!, inSection: 0)
    //The manual selection and call
    self.myTableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(localIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
    self.tableView(self.myTableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: localIndexPath)
    getCellHeight(localIndexPath)
    }
}

 //I just store the indexPath in a variable
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    NSLog("Und gewählter Index ist:  \(indexPath.row)")
    selectedRowIndex = indexPath
    myTableView.beginUpdates()
    print("did start updates")
    myTableView.endUpdates()
    print("did end updates")
    getCellHeight(selectedRowIndex)

}

//I use this function to check the height of the cell
func getCellHeight(indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    var cell = tableView(myTableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    print("HÖHE VON: \(indexPath.row) ist jetzt: \(cell.bounds.height)")
}

//I check wheter selectedIndexPath or localIndexPath are equal to the indexPath argument, if it is the cell should expand
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if(selectedRowIndex == indexPath && selectedRowIndex.row == indexPath.row || localIndexPath == indexPath){
        print("heightforrow CALLED für: \(indexPath.row)")
        return 200
   }
     print("heightforrow NOT CALLED für: \(indexPath.row)")
    return 60

}
```

Sorry for the prints in german, but I think you can make up what they mean(ist = is, für = for, höhe von = height of).

And here's the log when I tap the second cell, this is working fine, cell expands as I intended, even tho the heigh reads 44:

```
did start Updates
heightforrow NOT CALLED für: 0
heightforrow CALLED für: 1
heightforrow NOT CALLED für: 2
did end updates
HÖHE VON: 1 ist jetzt: 44.0
```

And this is the log when i tap an annotation, the cell isn't expanding visually:

```
did start updates
heightforrow NOT CALLED für: 0
heightforrow NOT CALLED für: 1
heightforrow CALLED für: 2
heightforrow NOT CALLED für: 0
heightforrow NOT CALLED für: 1
heightforrow CALLED für: 2
did end updates
HÖHE VON: 2 ist jetzt: 44.0
HÖHE VON: 2 ist jetzt: 44.0
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: You should summarise your question while asking.. That is too long question which takes too much time to read.

Comment: Problem can be with your `localIndexPath`. How do you calculate it?

Comment: Thank you, I will try that! This is my first post here, so I've got much to learn. 
@kelin I get have a String looking like Optional("Tour 2"), I use the advance method to get to the number and then convert it to Int, it looks like it works in the log, but I'll look further into that and let you know!

Comment: @NoLoHo, do you use autolayout?

Comment: @kelin no I disabled autolayout, but the View is added as a subview, could that have to do with the problem? The localindexpath variable is correct.

Comment: @NoLoHo, add breakpoints to `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and see the Debug navigator in Xcode to check what exactly happens, between the moment when you tap an annotation and height returned.

Comment: @kelin sorry for the late answer, I found an approach which works way better for what I had in mind than what I came up with. I will post it as an answer now. Nontheless I appreciate your efforts very much, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot to everybody who tried to help me with this problem!!! I tried everything but I wasn't able to make it work. While Researching I found an approach that works way better for what I wanted than my code posted here. Here's what I'm doing now: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWgr_wNtGPM
with the help of: [Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Cannot remove an observer - ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901926/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsrangeexception-reason-cannot-re)

Comment: I'm glad my video helped you. If you have any other questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you, I will if I have a question! Your video was really good and helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a function like below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44.00
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried using 200.00 and 44.00, but it didn't make a difference unfortunately.